# Not able to insert multiple check box data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to insert multiple check box data in one time in rest api web service. But i can insert only one data. 
This is my controller method

```
public function insert_code_post(){

        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $code_id = $this->input->post('code_id');

        $records = array();
        for($i=0; $i < count($code_id); $i++){
            $records[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'code_id' => $code_id[$i]);       
        }

                                $res = $this->my_model->insert_data($records);

                                if($res)
                                {
                                $data= array();
                                $data["error"]= false;
                                $data["status"] = 200;
                                $data["message"] = "Inserted...";
                                $this->response($data, 200);
                                }

    }
```

model method

```
public function insert_data($data)
        {
            foreach($data as $key => $value){
                $query = "insert into code (user_id, code_id) values ('".$value['user_id']."','".$value['code_id']."')"; 
            return  $this->db->query($query);

            }

        }
```

this is my client code, i use curl with simple html fields for test

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/my_controller/insert_code';
    $params = array();
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            //echo $check; 
            $params = array(
                    "user_id" => '2',
                    "code_id" => $check);

    }
      $curl = curl_init() or die(curl_error());
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $jobId = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $jobId;
    curl_close($curl);          

}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    </head>
<body>


    <form action="insert_multiple_CI.php" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="4">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="5">
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone suggest me how do i able to insert multiple data to my api, i tried many methods and also check related question in forum but not able solve.

Comment: "Multiple data"? Do you mean multiple rows at once, or more data in one column?

Comment: yes, multiple rows at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem with preparing request.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/my_controller/insert_code';

    // I see you are iterating code_id in rest handler. so it should be array.
    $params = array("user_id" => '2',
                    "code_id" => array());
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            //echo $check; 
            $params["code_id"][] = $check;
    }
      $curl = curl_init() or die(curl_error());
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $jobId = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $jobId;
    curl_close($curl);          

}

?>
```

You can also update your model code as suggested by Saty on above code.

Comment: Thank you @jagad89, its working. its on the client issue. your codes help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your model file to

**Model**

```
public function insert_data($data)
{
  $result=$this->db->insert_batch('code',$data);
  if ($result) {
  return $this->db->insert_id();
  } else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

And problem is with you CURL URL

```
 $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/my_controller/insert_code';
```

You have call `public function insert_code_post(){` this controller so your url would be

```
$baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/my_controller/insert_code_post';
```

Comment: getting database error,i am trying to insert multiple rows in one time.

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES (Array)' at line 1

INSERT INTO `code` (0) VALUES (Array)

Comment: on this line   $result=$this->db->insert('code',$data);

Comment: check updated code and what is the table name of your insert query

Comment: and what is the value of `$data` in your model file??

Comment: it can insert only one row. $data value are "user_id" and "code_id". code tables has these fields "id", user_id, code_id

Comment: its getting error when i put "_post" at end of my url. get this reponse from Codeigniter {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}